# Imprimir directamente a la impresora sin cuadro de diálogo con PHP o JS

Tags: php, html

Uso un método para imprimir diractamente a la impresora pero no me permite imprimir imágenes y otros formatos propios de HTML, lo hago de esta manera:

```html
$html = "<h1>Test de Impresión de Tickets</h1>";

$html = "Impresión automática desde la impresora escogida";

$printer='EPSON L210';

$enlace=printer_open($printer);

printer_write($enlace, $html);

printer_close($enlace);
```

Me funciona solo con texto plano pero no me imprime imagenes o textos con formato como negrita, cursiva o subrayado. Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: y esto se ejecuta del lado del cliente o del servidor?

Comment: Del lado del cliente se hace la petición, funciona perfecto ya que le activé el modulo printer en mi versión de PHP

Comment: Osea, haces la petición del lado del cliente y se imprime del lado del servidor?

Comment: Es correcto, me está funcionando pero imprime sin formato

Comment: si ejecutas el comando window.print(); de javascript?, seria valido para lo que quieres?

Comment: PrintArea.
https://plugins.jquery.com/PrintArea/ espero te sirva!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para darle formato es importante que veas el manual de php http://php.net/manual/fa/ref.printer.php
allí están todas las funciones a mi me funciono de maravillas
te pongo un ejemplo

```
$handle = printer_open("nombre de la impresora");
        printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw");
        printer_start_doc($handle, " Nombre del doc(esto no se imprime)");
        printer_start_page($handle);
//el codigo de printer_draw_bmp es para imprimir una imagen los numeros que //le siguen son el tamaño y posisiones
        printer_draw_bmp($handle, "direccion de la imagen", 215, 0, 110, 110);  
// el create font es para crear la fuente con fuente 
        $fontt = printer_create_font("Georgia", 38, 14, 100, false, false, false, 0);
//luego seleccionas las fuente que vas a usar
        printer_select_font($handle, $fontt);
//luego dibujas el texto con esa fuente y las cordenadas 
        printer_draw_text($handle, "Pones texto a imprimir", 95, 125);
        printer_delete_font($fontt);
```

Comment: Hola, funciona parcialmente; el documento queda en cola y no imprime. ¿Qué podrá ser?

Answer (score 2):

Imprimir HTML directamente por la impresora como lo quieres hacer no es posible.

Lo que le estás enviando a la impresora es el código HTML, es decir, las "instrucciones" que el navegador interpreta para renderizar esa código HTML gráficamente. A no ser que tu impresora venga con un módulo para interpretar y renderizar HTML (cosa que dudo), lo que quieres no se puede hacer... al menos no directamente.

Sí se podría realizar con pasos intermedios: usar algún motor de renderizado para generar una versión gráfica de la página web, guardar dicha versión en un formato que la impresora sí pueda interpretar (una imagen o quizás un PDF) y mandar dicho fichero a la impresora.

Comment: He creado una función para esto y funciona perfecto, solo que la salida impresa no me toma los tags html

Comment: Perfecto, no es posible incluir HTML; Gracias!

Comment: @c3media Pudiste solucionarlo? actualmente requiero imprimir desde mi servidor pago.

Comment: No, no he solucionado